# Animation in Changing the side of View Controller in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am making side menu bar on which when we click on button the view move backward which is parallely which i have already made it but i want one side to be get decrease in size on moving backward

Actually my question is that how can we change the size of one side of   Viewcontroller without affecting the size of other side by writing programe

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can transform your view using CATransform3D matrix.
You can find examples here:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1951182

Or take a look at this example:
http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2013/07/objectivec-3d-view-rotation-parallelepiped-cube/